# When should RestTemplate.exchange() be used instead of .get, .post, etc.?

Tags: spring

RestTemplate has HTTP method specific methods, such as get(), post(), etc., and exchange() methods in which the method type is specified. When should exchange() be preferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your implementation. There are times when you can't use a regular get() or post(), etc. and exchange() is needed.

My strategy is to use the get() or post() when I can, because it is easier read, and when either don't have the right functionality, I go with exchange().